Stepping up current of PWM control signal for DC motor control?
I am a controls engineer with little background in electronics, so forgive me if this is a simple question. I am trying to figure out a simple and reliable way I can implement PWM speed control on various BLDC motors using the PWM output from an NI DAQ. As you might imagine, the DAQ is unable to provide enough current to the motors to achieve adequate control.
I have some idea that I can create a PCB with a gate driver (we have some MCP1407s) that will allow me to drive a higher-current PWM with the DAQ control signal, but I am not sure the exact circuit configuration.
The attached photo looks similar to what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure what transistor or component values I should be using. I'm also not quite sure if this will even work the way I want.
Picture source - Diyodemag.com - MOSFET Divers Why You Need Them, https://diyodemag.com/education/mosfet_drivers_why_you_need_them


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does your BLDC motor not have PWM input directly? If not, switching it on the low side would have implications for other inputs/outputs to if, if any, tachto output and so on.

It does. All I need is for the PWM signal from the DAQ to be converted to PWM from another source so the PWM motor control signal isn't limited to the DAQ output current. So basically this is a relay/optocoupler type implementation for a PWM signal. That's it. Shouldn't be too hard

Such as? And what do you mean provide current limitation? I DON'T want current limitation. I literally just need to generate a 5V PWM signal from a source with a decent current capacity (1A or > should do it) that matches the PWM frequency and duty cycle from the DAQ (controller). That's it.

If your BLDC has PWM inputs, then you can drive them directly from the MCP1407.  It can supply up to 1Amp continuous.  If you need more info than that, please post info about the motors.
